# How to control Google Chrome from terminal

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu

In Ubuntu, to control Opera from the command line you would use the command

```
opera -remote "openURL(www.google.com)"
```

is there a command like that for Google Chrome? Using the command

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome www.google.com
```

just opens a new window.

Comment: Works for me, and should work in general.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [chromix](https://github.com/smblott-github/chromix) project might be what you're looking for.  It allows control of chrome and its tabs from the command line (or within a script).

Disclaimer: I'm it's author.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me, opening my personal website in a new Chrome window on Ubuntu Linux:

```
google-chrome http://dotancohen.com
```

It looks like you are missing the initial `http://` part.

Answer (score 2):

```
google-chrome google.com
```

Also if google Chrome is the default browser then it can be opened using:

```
xdg-open https://google.com
```

But `xdg-open` expects `https://` to be appended before the URL. If you don't add it then it will search for file on your local machine.

On Gnome this can be used (this will also use the default browser)

```
gnome-www-browser google.com
```

Taken from here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/19919/command-to-open-a-url

Answer (score 1):

Here is another (more generic) way to do that (assume chrome is your default browser) :

```
gnome-open http://superuser.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just do `chromium-browser` (for chromium), or `google-chrome`, and instead of depending on it being there in `/usr/bin/google-chrome` just rely on you PATH, or if you really want to know *exactly* where it is just type `which google-chrome` and it will give you the path note that the `which` command will tell you the *static* location of an application